# Jenkins parallel dynamic stage does not work

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I am using below code snippet for deploying code to multiple environments parallelly . For example I have two environments acpt, acpt2. The function
Deploy executes from shared library which loaded at first to below script . The problem is when it tries to deploy first environment “acpt” as its parallel stage it moves to “acpt2” environment and it never deploys to acpt environment. How to get around this issue ? Any thoughts?

```
    stage('Deployment Distribution') {
        steps {
            script {
                    
                    for (int i = 0; i < environments.size(); i++) {
                    env.environ = environments[i]
                    jobs["${env.environ}"] = {
                        
                        node("XXXXX") {
                            
                            stage("Deploy ${env.environ}") {
                            
                            
                            Deploy("${env.environ}")  /// This function is written in shared library
                    
                            sleep 10
                    
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
                parallel jobs
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's the parallel stage behaviour right? It will trigger the deployment in the same time for your both acpt and acpt2 env. 
I did not get your "The problem is when it tries to deploy first environment “acpt” as its parallel stage it moves to “acpt2” " point - could you clarify more ?

Comment: @SamitKumarPatel I might not have explained it properly. Eventhough they acpt and acpt2 trigger parallely, i want acpt2 deployment trigger with a delay ( 10 seconds) as the Deployment tool ( IBM Urban Code Deploy) does cannot hadle multiple requests same time. Is it possible to delay acpt2 deployment by 10 seconds –

Comment: don't you think in that case sequence is prefered than parallel with your scenario ? anyhow you are asking to wait for one deployment to finish for another. But "YES" can be achieved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally went with sequential deployment which is time consuming but no other option

Answer (score 0):

as we discuss in the comment, your expectation can be achieved like this :

In my below example with an If condition I have added `sleep` for the acpt2 parallel job.

```
node {
    jobs=[:]
    ['acpt','acpt2'].each {
        jobs["${it}"] = {
            stage("deploy") {
                // sleep 10 will add only in acpt2 deployment running parallel
                if("${it}" == "acpt2") {
                    sleep 10
                }
                echo "deployment"
            }
        }
        
        parallel jobs
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for response. This works great when i have 2 environments. But the idea of dynamic stage is i can have 2 parallel , 3 parallel or 4 parallel deployments. lets say if i have 3 environments then 2nd and 3rd environments should sleep for 10 seconds.4 parallel deployments 2nd, 3rd and 4th deployments should sleep 10 seconds. Above solution will only help me if i have 2 environments  Basically I am adding environment as environment variable

Comment: Also above example runs acpt two times

Comment: than I can say you have to strict with sequential pipeline rather than Parallel :).

Comment: Ok thanks. I will probably go with sequential.